# .setLocked changes name of forum post | Discord.js v14

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

I have this bot that, in this specific task, needs to reply to a user in a forum post, change the name, and then lock the post. This worked fine until I actually added the .setLocked. Here is a truncated version of my code:

```
export async function declineRequestReport(interaction) {
       await reply(interaction);
       await renameThread(interaction);
       closeThread(interaction);
}

function renameThread(interaction) {
    const forumPost = interaction.channel;
    const forumPostName = forumPost.name;
    forumPost.setName("This cool name");
}

function reply(interaction) {
    interaction.reply("This cool reply");
}

function closeThread(interaction) {
    const forumPost = interaction.channel;
    forumPost.setLocked(true);
}
```

When I run the code with line 4 commented out, the command is replied to, but I run the command fully, the command is replied to, the post gets renamed, but then the post is renamed back to what it was originally and the post is closed.

Why is this and how can I fix it?